# How do we implement an IS-A relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

The entities are `Programmer`, `Engineer` which both are `Employee`. I would like to explore the IS-A option in Entity Framework. Please can anyone tell me how to implement an "is-a" relationship with Entity Framework (code first or database fist)?

I have classes like this:

```
public abstract class Employee
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Programmer : Employee
{
     double HRate { get; set; }
}

public class Engineer: Employee
{
     double MRate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what version of EntityFramework are you using?

Comment: Entity Framework 6  latest one

Comment: then you may found [this link usefull](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Is-A relationship is inheritance and one possible way to implement that in EF could be like below:

```
public class Employee
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Programmer 
{
     [ForeignKey(nameof(Employee))]
     public  int Id { get ; set ; }
     public virtual Employee {get;set;}
     double HRate { get; set; }

}
public class Engineer: Employee
{
     [ForeignKey(nameof(Employee))]
     public  int Id { get ; set ; }
     public virtual Employee {get;set;}
     double MRate { get; set; }
}
```